# Unity При попытке идти вплотную к стене возникает дергание экрана

Tags: c#, unity3d, 2d

Когда персонаж подходит вплотную к стене и пытается идти дальше в ее сторону, экран начинает слегка дергаться, поскольку персонаж перемещается вперед за счет `transform.position` , а потом выталкивается назад, за счет BoxColider2D и Rigibody2D. Пытался решить проблему навесив GameObject'ы с BoxColider2D вокруг персонажа, но умений для этого не хватило. Как реализовать проверку на "стену"?

И еще 1 дополнительный вопрос: как изменять значение переменной класса XXX при работе в классе YYY?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 5.0f;
public Rigidbody2D playerRigibody;
public Animator charAnimator;
public SpriteRenderer sprite;
private void Awake()
{
    playerRigibody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    charAnimator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}

private void Move()
{
    Vector3 tempvectorX = Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    Vector3 tempvectorY = Vector3.up * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    transform.Translate(tempvectorX * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    transform.Translate(tempvectorY * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    if (tempvectorX.x < 0)
    {
        sprite.flipX = true;
    }
    else
    {
        sprite.flipX = false;
    }
}


void Start()
{

}

void Update()
{
    charAnimator.SetInteger("State", 0);
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal") || Input.GetButton("Vertical")){
        charAnimator.SetInteger("State", 1);
        Move();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `как изменять значение переменной класса XXX при работе в классе YYY?` - это уже похоже на какой-то локальный форс в метке unity, уже 3й или 4й такой вопрос за неделю.

Comment: Перемещение через Transform и физика - несовместимые вещи, так просто нельзя делать.

Comment: Полезно будет почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4